# Is it possible to disable the element created by ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have implemented a directive which decides whether it will render an element or not.

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

export class MyDirective {

    constructor(private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @Input() set method() {
        this._viewContainer.clear();
        if (// some logic here //) {
            this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef) // render element
        }
}
```

My problem now is I want to render the element but I also need to decide whether it is enabled or not. Is there a way to do this within the directive itself?

Comment: `cdk` is best way but hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done the same way it is done in built-in [`ngIf` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.0/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L135-L142):

```
if (// some logic here //) {
    this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef) // render element
} else {
    this._viewContainer.clear();
}
```

Comment: So on `else` it will not render the element right? I need it rendered but disabled.

Comment: Yes, it won't render it and clear the view if it was previously rendered. It's unclear what 'disabled' is supposed to mean in your case. It's not a tech term, unless the element is form input.

Comment: Yes, by disabled I mean view-able but not editable, like form input.

Comment: Then the appropriate `disabled` attribute should be set on the element. There are no form inputs in the question, and 'disabled' isn't applicable to any random element or the template in whole.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well, I am rendering an element and making it `disabled` I think is a technical term and should be understandable. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So 'element' is the element that this directive is defined on or some element from the template? If the one from the template then which one? A template can contain multiple elements. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains how the directive is supposed to work in your case.

Comment: it is not possible.

Comment: @estus sorry it is for Gerald.

Comment: @M.Laida Consider addressing it with `@`. Without it only answer's author receives a notification if there are several participants,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, maybe should try to display a dummy component, if you do not want to clear (this._viewContainer.clear()) it.

```
  @Input() set method() {
    this._viewContainer.clear();
    if (// some logic here //) {
        this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef) // render element
    } else {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DummyComponent);
        this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
    }
  }
```

- DummyComponent - Create a dummyComponent you want to display